# Was this question closed because a new user made an (easily correctable) Markdown formatting mistake and (correctable, ESL) grammar?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, close-reasons, formatting

[WSL2 duplicated terminal](https://superuser.com/q/1756353/1210833) was Mod-closed as "Needs clarity or details", but even as originally written it was (again) quite understandable to me.  It definitely had two problems:

- The new user made a simple Markdown formatting error in that only one line break was placed between paragraphs rather than two.  You can see this in the (almost identical) side-by-side edit on [Revision 2](https://superuser.com/posts/1756353/revisions) that I made.
- The grammar is poor, but not unreadable.  Clearly the user is not a native-English speaker, and that should be okay here -- We don't all have that luxury. The community can assist with grammar clean-up, and hopefully help the user improve through the process.

  I have not yet had a chance to clean up the grammar myself, but I will.  However, with the addition of the paragraph breaks, the question should at least be understandable by a casual reader.  Would the question simply have been closed for the grammar you see in Revision #2?  Not typically, I wouldn't think.

Perhaps I'm missing some other reason why someone would VTC this as unclear, but [again](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14757/1210833), if the question as-written is understandable (and answerable by) a subject-matter-expect on the topic, it's *not unclear*.

So should the question have been force-closed for such a simple and easily correctable formatting error and poor grammar?  Are these truly valid close-reasons (let alone Mod-close reasons)?

I've made excuses for mods here before in assuming that they have a *lot* to review and can't spend time editing-to-improve, but (a) I've been told by one of the mods in chat that this isn't really the case -- They are *not* overwhelmed and have time to help, and (b) it took less than 5 seconds to fix the formatting issue.

Isn't closing a question (especially Mod-closing) *supposed* to be reserved for those that aren't salvageable by the community?  Shouldn't a Mod give the community a chance to review and fix those that are easily correctable (if not fix them themselves)?

Related "general" (not question-specific) Meta posts:

- [I think SU has a newbie-biting problem](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14369/1210833)
- [PSA: Just because *you* don't understand a question doesn't automatically make it unclear](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14757/1210833)
- [We have bad question closing habits](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14725/1210833)
- [Why are mod-close rates so much higher for Super User than for other similar SE sites?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14682/1210833)

Comment: I don't get what the question is about after reading even the corrected version 

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Most people wouldn't, I agree, but someone with experience in the nuances of Windows Terminal and WSL should.  It's not an *easy* question, regardless, but IMHO that makes it an even better one (once cleaned up).  I'll work on cleaning up the grammar on it, which should make it more clear even to a non-SME.  I don't have the *answer* yet, but I do have some suspicions on what's going wrong.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It's likely *somewhat* related to [one of these two questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A1210833+icon+windows+terminal+ubuntu+fragment), with a touch of another underlying issue as well.  The second one of those (which almost got closed as a duplicate) was pretty tough to figure out, but I happened almost by chance to end up reproducing the issue.

Comment: “The grammar is poor, but not unreadable.” - Great, an editor can improve the quality of the question and it will be placed in the queue to be reopened. What shouldn’t happen, is a question with poor grammar, be reopened without being edited. A question with grammatical mistakes should be closed so it can be improved in my opinion

Comment: @Ramhound If 5 community members deem it unsalvageable before 1 community member is kind enough to help out an ESL new contributor, then so be it.  But mod-closing short-circuits the community process.  It should be reserved for truly garbage posts.  This wasn't.

Comment: You mention it being "place in the queue" to be reopened, but for some reason have no problem with it completely skipping the queue to be closed.