# Use of ChatGPT is now banned on Super User

Tags: discussion, announcement, chatgpt

Following the discussion ([Should we ban ChatGPT on Super User? - Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14847/should-we-ban-chatgpt-on-super-user)) regarding the usage of [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/) to generate questions or answers on Super User the community have voted in favour of a ban <sup>(1)</sup>.

<sup>(1) The highest voted answer by a big margin is [that by forest](https://meta.superuser.com/a/14848/337631).</sup>

As a result going forwards AI generated questions and answers are not allowed on Super User and will be removed with no prior warning. In addition, users may be suspended or deleted.

See Also:

[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) <sup>(2)</sup>

<sup>(2) ChatGPT is an Artificial Intelligence based chat bot by OpenAI, which was announced on 2022-11-30. Use of ChatGPT is currently available to the public for free.</sup>

Comment: Bad policy.  ETA of fix?

Comment: @sgfit What fix? If you believe it is a bad policy you are free to argue your case with an answer at [Should we ban ChatGPT on Super User? - Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14847/should-we-ban-chatgpt-on-super-user)

Comment: @ZioBit there's a few tells for humans and tools to detect it to an extent. Also quite a lot of it is nearly plausible garbage.

Comment: @ZioBit after having played a bit with ChatGPT, I now find relatively easy to recognize an answer written by ChatGPT. It has its own style, which is quite different from the styles of most of the contributors, it tends to enumerate point after point, and while the answer may look satisfactory to a non-specialist, it is either flawed in some details or overall dull.

Comment: @ZioBit Have you ever been to one of those "how to fix X" websites that list a bunch of very well written steps, but they're mostly generic or don't make sense for this problem and you're sure that the person who wrote that is completely clueless and just rewords top results from Google? If an answer is like that, but you can't find the original source, it's ChatGPT.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek wrote *"...plausible garbage."*  Exactly.  Well said.  And it explains why Elon Musk fears it so much, as it competes with him so directly.

Comment: Will the review process contain an extra flag "Seems to be generated by A.I."?

Answer (score 2):

To paraphrase **Mel Brooks' legendary [Blazing Saddles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1lyNt5km8U)**,

## Robots, we don't need no stinkin' robots!

(which, of course, paraphrased the epic [Treasure of Sierra Madre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8WbLU958Lg))

Comment: It is also part of Stack Overflow's history, Stack Overflow cofounder [Atwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood)'s 2008-07-12 blog post *[Stack Overflow Badge Feedback](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/12/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/)* (though the [search engines ***refuse*** to reveal it](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2023/02/27/stinking-badges-stack-overflow-and-broken-search-engines/)).