# Reference new ChatGPT / AI policy in the Help Center

Tags: discussion, help-pages

I've recently flagged a few answers as suspected ChatGPT generated answers.  These answers came from a new user.

It occurred to me to reference the help center when commenting to the user, however there is no mention (that I see) about this anywhere.

I think at least a link to this question
[Use of ChatGPT is now banned on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14862/use-of-chatgpt-is-now-banned-on-super-user)

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Yeah, I know it's a hot-button topic and I'm just coming up to speed on some of it...  I'll keep reading and keep that meta.se question handy.